# Is there a way to display and search all configured keyboard shortcuts in sublime 3?

Tags: search, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, text-editor

There are two features I'm really missing in **sublime text 3**:

- Fully functioning integrated terminal - like in geany (yes, I know about `Glue` but its not functioning like a normal terminal)
- **Searchable** display of **all currently active, configured keyboard shortcuts** of **all packages** with short description and package name.

While I can live without the former (but would love to get a comment in this direction), I suspect there is some function or user script/plugin that does the latter. I just couldn't find anything. I'm really tired of looking through rather cryptic text configuration files of many packets just to find out the short cut was overwritten by jet another package's shortcut. Care to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Keith Hall's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36132568/1426065) works well enough, there's already a plugin in Package Control that has numerous features: [**`FindKeyConflicts`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts) by skuroda. You can search for all key maps, all conflicts, direct conflicts, overlap conflicts, single package conflicts (all within one package), and a very useful one: multiple package conflicts, where you can choose the packages you suspect are conflicting and test only them. This is great for when you have packages like [LaTeXTools](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXTools) or [Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) installed that have about a million key combos (no offense to them, I love those packages) and you know the problem isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding a searchable display of all currently active keyboard shortcuts, you can easily create a plugin to do this:

- From the `Tools` menu -> `Developer` -> `New Plugin`
- Replace the contents of the template with the following:

  ```
  import sublime, sublime_plugin

  class ShowMappedKeysCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
      def run(self, edit):
          files = sublime.find_resources('*.sublime-keymap')

          items = []
          for file in files:
              contents = sublime.load_resource(file)
              mapped = sublime.decode_value(contents)

              for mapping in mapped:
                  items.append((file, mapping['keys'], mapping['command']))

          self.view.window().run_command('new_file')
          view = self.view.window().active_view()
          view.insert(edit, 0, '\n'.join(repr(item) for item in items))
  ```
- save it in the default folder, naming it something like `show_mapped_keys.py`

Then you can either map a key to the newly created `show_mapped_keys` command, or just execute it from the Sublime Console (`View` menu -> `Show Console` -> `sublime.active_window().active_view().run_command('show_mapped_keys')`)

This will create a new tab with a list of all the active configured keyboard bindings, showing where it was defined (i.e. either the package that it belongs to, or your user keybindings file), what the keys are, and the name of the command that the keybinding will execute.  This is then searchable as normal.

Obviously, if there are conflicts, this won't show you which has priority. One way to find that out would be to execute `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the console before trying the relevant keybinding, and seeing which command gets executed.

Comment: Note that the `Tools->Developer` menu is currently only available in the dev builds.

Comment: Dude this is gold!  I was planning on doing exactly this, but it got backlogged by a few other projects.  Know of any way to include args in the output?  I tried adding `mapping['args']` and it drops a `KeyError`.

Comment: @Enteleform I would guess that not all key mappings have arguments, so you could do `mapping.get('args', None)`, which will output `None` if the `args` key doesn't exist, otherwise the `args` :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Might try to work something out with this after I wrap some stuff up. It would be awesome to have a  QuickPanel with sub-QuickPanels per `sublime-keymap` so you can quickly brush up on your bindings

Comment: @Enteleform from [MattDMo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36134050/4473405), it sounds like the FindKeyConflicts package is worth looking at, maybe it already can display the bindings in that format :)

Comment: Thank you Keith! Although I accepted the other answer, because installing a plugin via package manager is easier and the plugin offers more functionally, I really learned something about writing sublime plugins from your answer. Very helpful! I had looked into it earlier but the API documentation concerning key bindings was not very helpful to me. Your example is all people working with key bindings in sublime really need.